# How can I disable these annoyances on Facebook? Disable Like Page Invites, Hide Seen, Disable Video Calls

Tags: facebook

I'd like to:

- Disable invite for liked pages
- Disable Facebook video calls on Android
- Hide seen Facebook

I spend a lot of time travelling and interacting with people. Sometimes I get 40-50 incoming video calls per day. Disabling notifications on my Android phone doesn't fix this.

I have people that get upset when they can see I saw their message, but don't respond quickly.

I also get around 60 friend requests per week from strangers.

And around 75% of my notifications on facebook.com are... "invited you to like" their page.

I'm already limiting my time on Facebook and Messenger severely, but there are too many advantages for me currently, to completely abandon the platform. So I'm looking for technical solutions, not for lifestyle solutions, e.g. just block all your customers.

Comment: What version of android are you running? That will help to answer some of these.

Answer (score 5):

Well, unfortunately we Facebook users simply **can’t** block invitations to "like" pages yet (as of June, 2020)

However, **here’s what you *can* do:** on a desktop browser, visit this page: https://www.facebook.com/pages/?category=invites. It aggregates all of your page invites in a single place, and you can dismiss them one by one (click on the **`×`** that appears on hover).

---

**Additional references:**

> *There’s one major omission in the [list of blocking options]: stopping page invites on Facebook. Anyone who likes a page can invite their friends to like it as well, and Facebook even encourages you to do this sometimes. You’ve almost certainly been swarmed with page invites on Facebook at some point.*
>
> *Unfortunately, there’s currently no way to turn off page invites on Facebook. Based on our testing, locking event invites doesn’t stop page invites.*
>
> [Make Use Of (dated 06 May, 2020)](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/complete-guide-blocking-facebook-invites/)

> *(…) All of a sudden, out of the blue, I am getting dozens and dozens of invites to “like” someone’s Facebook page.*
>
> *At first, I thought it was a side effect of having a pool of Facebook friends approaching the magic 5,000 number. (…)*
>
> *Upon further informal research, I don’t believe this is the case. I asked a small group of people in the office, and they have ALL seen a tremendous increase in page invites on their Facebook account.*
>
> [A blog post (dated 06 December, 2019)](https://fun107.com/why-am-i-getting-so-many-facebook-page-invites/)

---

**Update (as of December, 2020):** *On the new Facebook design/layout, that page still works on desktop browsers. Now there’s a wide blue* **`️ Accept`** `[to follow]` or  **`Accept`** `[to like]` *option – click on the gray button* `⋯` *next to it, and then select* `⊗ Decline`*. (Please note it’s also available as the last option in the left sidebar, as* **`⁺ Invites`***.)*

Comment: 1 click for liking and 3 clicks for not accepting the like on the new design. Painful

Answer (score -1):

1. Probably the easiest way to stop  any notification you don't like is to click on the notifications tab in the Facebook app > click the three dots > click "turn off notifications about ..."
   [image]

On desktop disable notifications in the account settings [here](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications). This can be done in the mobile app by clicking the three bars to open the menu > settings > notification settings.

2. In the messenger app under settings you can change notifications to turn off "vibrate on ring" but you can't fully turn off video calls. If one person keeps calling you then you can stop that by blocking them.
3. There is no way to turn off read receipts on Facebook Messenger Android.
4. To stop getting friend requests from strangers you'll need to go into your "Privacy settings" [here](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=privacy&section=canfriend&view) and change "who can send you friend requests" I recommend setting it to "friends of friends." However, if you  already have received a lot of spam friend requests you'll need to go into your friends list and remove people you don't know to limit who can friend request you. Additionally, if someone wants to add you that you don't have a mutual friend with you'll have to add them.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ray. Unfortunately for Like Page invites, after clicking on the "..." on the notification. I only have the options to: "Remove this notification" or "Report issue to Notifications Team"

Comment: Then I suggest going into the settings to turn off that notification type manually.

Comment: How do I do that? I tried looking in settings and can't find that option. Thank you!